# React. preventDefault() for onCopy event does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to make the clipboard events return `false` on the onCopy event. I use for test the `onCopy` handler and `e.preventDefault()` method. But text is copied without obstacles to the buffer! What is I miss?

Thank You in Advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import './index.css';


class Copy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      time: '',
      timer: false,
      counter: 0
    };

    this.handlerCopy = this.handlerCopy.bind(this);
  }

  handlerCopy(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // must prevent the current event

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counter: prevState.counter + 1
    }));

    alert('Don\'t copy it!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p onCopy={this.handlerCopy}>Copy me!</p>
        <p>Copy count: {this.state.counter}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Copy />,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a really good question!

This happens because React’s actual event listener is also at the root of the document, meaning the click event has already bubbled to the root. You can use `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent other event listeners.

Try it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import './index.css';


class Copy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      time: '',
      timer: false,
      counter: 0
    };

    this.handlerCopy = this.handlerCopy.bind(this);
  }

  handlerCopy(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counter: prevState.counter + 1
    }));

    alert('Don\'t copy it!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p onCopy={this.handlerCopy}>Copy me!</p>
        <p>Copy count: {this.state.counter}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Copy />,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Very interesting... I previously does not know about `nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation`... Oh, this React))

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation.
I think e.preventDefault() is enough for (at least) React 16.

[Working example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/82xnrnz3qj)

Comment: I do not understand why, but in my case it does not work (

Comment: What is your React version?

Comment: I have a 16 version

Comment: Sorry for bothering, what is the **exact** version? I tried this on local with React version 16.2.0 now and it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution which is mentioned doesn't seems working for me, but if talk about counter values in state its getting managed properly by writing handlerCopy in below manner(Updation of state values).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      time: '',
      timer: false,
      counter: 0
    };
  }

   handlerCopy(e) {
    var val = this.state.counter;
    val = val + 1;
    this.setState({
      counter: val
    }, function(){
      console.log('new acounter:- ', this.state.counter);
    })
    alert('Don\'t copy it!');
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p onCopy={(e) => this.handlerCopy(e)}>Copy me!</p>
        <p>Copy count: {this.state.counter}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('propagation',e)
  }, false);


export default App;
```

This handlerCopy function mentioned above is not making any changes for me @Max Wolfen

```
 handlerCopy(e) {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counter: prevState.counter + 1
    }));

    alert('Don\'t copy it!');
  }
```