# Can't trigger onCopy event in react 15

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to prevent text from being copied on a page by using the onCopy event handler. But it seems that the handler is not being triggered at all.

The code:

```
  handleCopy (e) {
    console.log('Hello world');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  render () {
    const { id, className, ...props } = this.props;
    const fullClassName = className ? `sr-only ${className}` : 'sr-only ok';
    return (
      <span className={fullClassName} id={id} {...props}
        onCopy={(e) => this.handleCopy(e)}>
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

style:

```
.sr-only {
  user-select: none;
}
```

I've been using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173522/react-preventdefault-for-oncopy-event-does-not-work/55025073#55025073) as a reference.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: try remove  {...props}

Comment: If you just put `onCopy={() => alert('test')}` does that work?

Comment: My guess is you're not directly inside the span element when copying. This code should work.

Comment: @FrankerZ, I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Correct way is  onCopy={this.handleCopy}. Here e is auto passed. Try below code snippet. It will work.

```
handleCopy(e) {
    console.log('Hello world');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  render() {
    const { id, className, ...props } = this.props;
    const fullClassName = className ? `sr-only ${className}` : 'sr-only ok';
    return (
      <span className={fullClassName} id={id} {...props}
        onCopy={this.handleCopy}>
        {this.props.children}
      </span>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScreenReaderMessage extends BcReactComponent {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
    }

    handleCopy (e) {
      console.log('Hello world');
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }

    render () {
      const { id, className, ...props } = this.props;
      const fullClassName = className ? `sr-only ${className}` : 'sr-only ok';
      return (
        <span className={fullClassName} id={id} {...props}
            onCopy={(e)=>this.handleCopy(e)}
            onContextMenu={(e)=>this.handleCopy(e)}
          >
          {this.props.children}
        </span>
      );
    }
  }

  ScreenReaderMessage.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    localeKey: PropTypes.string,
    children: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node), PropTypes.node]).isRequired
  };

  export default ScreenReaderMessage;
```

Hope it will help..

Comment: Are you using react 15.0.0 or higher??

Comment: I'm using react v15.4.1

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  } here is my dependencies yet it still worked for me

Comment: Try creating new react app and  test your this part of code